# Is there a way I can send a key press (sendkeys) to a remote computer

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-7, wmi, remote-desktop

Here's my problem. I have a joker who has been rotating displays to be upside down.  I don't know who it is, but when I find them I may need to find another topic on how to hide a body.

What I need to do is be able to send a key press combination (ctrl+alt+up) to fix the orientation.  Is there a way to send this if I have the computers name?
or
Is there a way I can set the orientation thru WMI?

Comment: Why not simply disable the shortcut key in Intel video options?

Comment: He may not have Intel video options.

Comment: It will be likely much much easier to fix this via WMI or similar than doing a "remote sendkeys".

Comment: Also you may want to take a read through this article showing [how to disable screen rotation via Group Policy](http://blog.foreignkid.net/2013/04/gpo-wmi-filter-prevent-screen-rotation/) (if you are using Intel graphics adapters).